# How to print a specified warning when installing package on partially-supported NodeJS version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I'm working on [`paraquire`](https://github.com/nickkolok/paraquire) - security-oriented alternative to usual `require`. Due to `NodeJS` internal issues `paraquire` runs on `NodeJS <= 0.11.0`, but cannot provide full protection.
I know about `engines` option in `package.json`, but I want to print a particular warning with more information.

Can I do this without using `npm` install scripts ?
(Install scripts tend to be insecure)